# Ho to convert an Arraylist<Person> to Map<String, List<Long>> with Stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Person ArrayList

```
List<Person> personList = getPersonList();
```

And I want to create a map of `Map<String, List<Long>>`

key based on Person::getDepartment and value based on a `List<Long>` of timestamps `Person::getTimestamp`

There are multiple Person records in the `List<Person> personList`, so I need to remove duplicates on `Person::getDepartment`, but since a Map doesn't let key duplicates, that should not be a problem, i think.

I can do that perfect with a forach loop but my question is can I do that with only one stream?

```
public class Person {

    private String department;
    private long timestamp;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the collect, use `groupingBy()` to group `Person` by department and `mapping()` to map the `Person` to its timestamp.

```
Map<String, List<Long>> map = 
personList.stream()
          .collect(groupingBy(
                         Person::getDepartment,
                         mapping(Person::getTimestamp, toList())
                        )
                  );
```

And add these imports :

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

or just :

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```

Comment: Thanx for your quick answer, but I get this error ')' expected. And When i add extra ')' then i get another error mesage Cannot resolve method 'collect(java.util.stream.Collector<T,capture<?>,java.util.Map<K,java.util.List<T>>>, java.util.stream.Collector<T,capture<?>,R>)'

Comment: You are welcome. I added the static imports and the missing `)`. It should be fine.

Comment: Perfect, thanx.

Comment: Is there a way to add distinct() in that stream to prevent duplicates of long values? Or should I ask a new question? I can do that by toSet method for sure but I prefer an ArrayList. Thanx

Comment: Just replace `toList()` by `toSet()` if the order doesn't matter. If the order matters, `Collectors.collectingThen()` could interest you. If really you don't manage to do that, create a new answer but I advise you to try multiple times (even if not easy) because this will allow you to really progress.